# Renaming a categorical variable based on values of other variable in R

Tags: r

I have a sample dataset 'a' like this:

```
> a
  group marks  upd class
1     T     2   up     A
2     C     3   up  <NA>
3     C     4 down     B
4     T     5   up  <NA>
5     T     6 down     D
6     C     7   up  <NA>
7     T     1 down  <NA>
8     T     0 down     G
```

Here for each group (T or C) there are records in 'class' variable with values and null. Now for each group where ever the class is null ,I want that group to be renamed as T-NULL or C-NULL respectively. If the group (T or c) has some value in 'class' ,the group name should be as it is. How can we write a code in R for this?

Comment: Oh ok.. I am sorry.I didnt know this. I will post my question in stackoverflow. Thank you..

Comment: I'll migrate the question, mostly because I think SO would produce better answers, but it's not crazy to ask R-related questions here.

Comment: Can you show your desired output? Also, is `group` is class `factor` or `character`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
assign_group = function(class,group){
        if(is.na(class)){ new_group = paste0(group,"NULL")}else{new_group=paste0(a$group,"NULL")}
return(new_group)}
a$new_group = sapply(a$class,assign_group,a$group)
```

Comment: `if` statement can't handle a vector input

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 ifelse(is.na(a$class),paste(a$group,"NULL",sep="-"),paste(a$group))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dplyr approach:

```
require(dplyr)
b <- a %>% mutate(new_class = ifelse(group %in% c("T","C") & is.na(class),paste(group,"NULL",sep="-"),class)
```

Or data.tables

```
require(data.table)
a[,':='(= ifelse(group %in% c("T","C") & is.na(class),paste(group,"NULL",sep="-"),class))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing approach !

```
a$class[is.na(a$class)] <- paste0(a$group[is.na(a$class)],"-NULL")
```